# Return value from function and place into variable in separate function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to obtain the value of var newtotal from a separate function, which then passes the value on to a PHP script via Ajax.

Here's my code: `

```
function customerCost(){

        var newtotal;

        var start = document.getElementById('source').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
        var via = document.getElementById('via').value;

        if(via != ""){
        var waypts = [];

        waypts.push({
            location:via,
            stopover:false});

        var newrequest = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          waypoints: waypts,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(newrequest, function(newresponse, newstatus) {
          if (newstatus == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var newtotal = 0;
            var mynewroute = newresponse.routes[0];
             for (i = 0; i < mynewroute.legs.length; i++) {
                 newtotal += mynewroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                }
                            return newtotal;
            }

        });

        }else{

            var newrequest = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(newrequest, function(newresponse, newstatus) {
          if (newstatus == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var newtotal = 0;
            var mynewroute = newresponse.routes[0];
             for (i = 0; i < mynewroute.legs.length; i++) {
                 newtotal += mynewroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                }
                return newtotal;
            }

        });

        }



    }
```

I am then calling the value from within a separate function with the following:

```
customertotal = customerCost();
```

I am only getting an "undefined" error. However if I replace the `return newtotal;` for `alert(newtotal);` then it outputs the correct value.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `directionsService.route()` call is asynchronous.  That means that when you call it, it only starts the operation and your `customerCost()` function continues and finishes long before the `.route()` ajax call has finished and called its callback.

You are trying to program in a synchronous fashion with an asynchronous operation.  You can't do that.  Your `customerCost()` function call cannot return the `newtotal` value because it isn't known yet at the time that function returns.

Instead, you need to learn how to program in an asynchronous way.  Any code that needs the `newtotal` value needs to either be in the callback where that value is available or you can call a function from there and pass it the `newtotal` value.

A typical way to develop something like this might be with your own callback:

```
function customerCost(cb){

        var newtotal;

        var start = document.getElementById('source').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
        var via = document.getElementById('via').value;

        if(via != ""){
        var waypts = [];

        waypts.push({
            location:via,
            stopover:false});

        var newrequest = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          waypoints: waypts,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(newrequest, function(newresponse, newstatus) {
          if (newstatus == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var newtotal = 0;
            var mynewroute = newresponse.routes[0];
             for (i = 0; i < mynewroute.legs.length; i++) {
                 newtotal += mynewroute.legs[i].distance.value;
              }
              // call the callback and pass it the newtotal
              cb(newtotal);
            }

        });

        }else{

            var newrequest = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(newrequest, function(newresponse, newstatus) {
          if (newstatus == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var newtotal = 0;
            var mynewroute = newresponse.routes[0];
             for (i = 0; i < mynewroute.legs.length; i++) {
                 newtotal += mynewroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                }
                // call the callback and pass it the newtotal
                cb(newtotal);
            }

        });

    }
}


// call the asynchronous cost function and process the result
// in a callback function
customerCost(function(newtotal) {
    // the newtotal value is available here
});
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. I've learnt something new today. Thank you very much for your patience & assistance.

Answer (score 1):

you should use callback function to work with variables inside asynchronous functions.

You can add a callback function as parameter:

```
customerCost(callback){

  // your original code
}
```

Then replace all line like `return newtotal` by `callback(newtotal);`

Then invoke function `customerCost` like:

```
customerCost(function(customertotal){
  // work with customertotal
});
```